# Marketing cloud Email automation from Salesforce apex/rest-api

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I am looking to build functionality where I can completely build an email body as well as the list of recipients within apex then make a callout to Marketing cloud passing it all the data to then send the email. I am having issues finding documentation to help as I am trying to do this. Currently I am able to callout and authenticate into Marketing cloud and get a refresh token but I can't find documentation on what functions to do the next steps (sending an email). I found messageDefinitionSends but this seems to be to send something from a journey item which is not what I'm looking to do. I am basically looking to send an email using a salesforce report for the recipients as you can do in the UI of Marketing cloud but through the API.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [MessageDefinitionSends](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/messageDefinitionSends.htm) is the correct REST API method. Alternatively, you can use the SOAP API as [documented here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/triggered_email_scenario_guide_for_developers.htm).

With either method you will need to firstly create a new Subscriber Profile Attribute in Email App > Subscribers > Profile Management. Ensure that the attribute name is prefixed with `HTML__` (two underscores) as this overrides the max 4000 character length.

Next, you need to create an email and insert `%%HTML__YourAttributeName%%` where the HTML should appear in your email.

You can then create a Triggered Send Email using the email you just created from Email App > Interactions > Triggered Emails.

Start the Triggered Email and then use the Attribute in your request. For example:

```
Host: https://www.exacttargetapis.com
POST /messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:cust_key/send
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

{
    "From": {
        "Address": "simon@sausage.com",
        "Name": "Simon Sausage"
    },
    "To": {
        "Address": "example@example.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "example@example.com",
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "HTML__emailBody": "<body>hello world</body>"
            }
        }
    },
    "OPTIONS": {
        "RequestType": "ASYNC"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eliot,
I will take a look into this today. How would this work if I was trying to send to multiple subscribers? List them as comma delimited or multiple calls?

Comment: Additionally I am having trouble locating the "entry event send definition". I am not sure how to locate it to find the ID or Cust_Key. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, you can't use this method to send to multiple subscribers. The `cust_key` value is the external key of the triggered email. You can view this at Email app > Interactions > Triggered Emails > External Key column (in the table).

Comment: Thanks!!I'm able to move past that now! Now onto solving my next errors of formatting the request how it wants haha.

Comment: Great, if I answered your question then please could you mark it as accepted for the benefit of others.

Comment: I get back a 202 Accepted code but then has a response body of [{"recipientSendId":"","hasErrors":true,"messages":["InvalidOrMissingTo"]}]

Comment: Is your To Address missing or invalid by any chance?

Comment: The body of the request is:
 {"From": {"Address": "jlong@innovateteam.com","Name": "Josh Long"},"To": {"Address": "jlong@innovateteam.com","SubscriberKey": "jlong@innovateteam.com","ContactAttributes": {"SubscriberAttributes": {"HTML__emailBody": "<body>hello world</body>"}}},"OPTIONS": {"RequestType": "ASYNC"}}

It's as shown just with different address..

Comment: Have you tried using a different email address? Can you try [validating the email address](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/validateEmail.htm) to confirm that it's valid?

Comment: It's my email address, Is the email supposed to be something specific to marketing cloud? I will try a few more things tomorrow but I have tried another email address as well with the same result.

Comment: Hi @JoshuaLong, that request should work. Let's move this offline for now. If you [connect with me](http://www.linkedin.com/in/eliot) then we can setup a brief webinar and look at this together.

Comment: UGH! Shoot myself in the foot...
I was adding the header "Content" When I needed to have "Content-Type"
Both calls return successfully but I don't receive any email.

Comment: Hi Josh, to send to multiple subscribers, you will need to use the SOAP API method. Refer to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/eliotharper/cf5c99cc979728f123d818dbb4e9f8d2).